# IBM Ready Healthcare app migration from v6.3 to v8.0 issue

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to migrate the IBM Ready Healthcare app (https://github.com/IBM-MIL/IBM-Ready-App-for-Healthcare) from v6.3 to v8.0.

I ran "mfpmigrate client ..." command from 'healthcare-mfpf' folder (folder structure shown below), and I got "No supported platforms were detected to migrate" error. Next, I ran the command "mfp add environment" in order to add the environment, that would add the platform. However, I get an error saying that there needs to be a hybrid app available to add environment. I had no luck on running the commands from apps folder as well (folder structure shown below).

Would anyone please kindly let me know the folder I should run the command from, or do I need to go through some extra steps before I can run the "mfpmigrage client ..." command.

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCkrY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Notice: please note that the Ready Apps are no longer maintained by IBM. Just take this under considerations

This project is a Hybrid app, meaning you need to first add it to MobileFirst Studio and then add a supported environment. The project does not come with environments by default.

Only once you do this step will the migration tool find a platform (= environment) to migrate from...

Looking at the file structure you've provided, it's wrong.
It shows:

Apps
- android
- iphone

It's supposed to be:

Apps
- some app
--- android
--- iphone
--- common

It could be that they call the app in the platform name, but that doesn't matter, it still needs to have the environment folder, so maybe to "Android" you need to add the "Android environment" (right-click > add environment...).

It could be because you thought this is Cordova app and used `mfp add environment` in the wrong filesystem location (also looks like you're trying to use a CLI instead of Studio?).

Looking at the GitHub repository, this whole structure is unconventional and it's not clear why they did it this way.

The links to the documentation there are also dead. This looks like a dead project.